# What is this fantasy system where you roll d10s and find matches and runs?

Tags: product-identification

I've heard of a RPG system where the dice mechanic is rolling several d10s and then looking for either the highest number among them, matching numbers, or sets of at least 3 dice that have consecutive numbers.

It was a fantasy game, but I don't remember anything else about it. The dice mechanic kind of reminded me of Cthulhutech, which I'm playing right now. What game is it?

Comment: That mechanic sounds somewhat similar to the One Roll Engine. If that's what you're looking for, *Reign* is the fantasy game that uses ORE. Is that it?

Comment: Hello, Adrian, and welcome to the site.  @SevenSidedDie: That sounds like an actual answer to me; submit it and I'll upvote.

Comment: @Tynam I was reluctant to post it and I had to think about why when you asked—looking at the original question before editing, this isn't actually a sys-rec question but a product-id question that just isn't very clear that it's a prod-id question, which explains my being tentative. I'll fix the question and post that as an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That dice mechanic – pools of d10s, high numbers matter but so do matches and sometimes runs – sounds like the One Roll Engine.

ORE is a little different than you describe, but pretty close: you don't look for *single* high numbers, but sets of matched numbers in pairs or more, and both the face number of the set (called "height") and the number of matching dice (called "width") matter to what happens. (There are also ORE variants that use runs of numbers like you describe.) Usually height determines the quality of the result, while width determines how skillfully it was done. For example, when hitting someone, height determines hit location with higher hit locations being more vulnerable (10 is the head), while width determines the damage. Hence the "one roll" in the system's name.

The One Roll Engine is used in a lot of games, but the only straight-up fantasy game that uses it is *Reign* (if you want a system with a setting) or *Reign Enchiridion* (if you just want the system from *Reign*). If you want to take a look at a ORE game to see if the mechanic matches what you're looking for, *[Nemesis](http://www.rpgnow.com/product_info.php?products_id=90427&affiliate_id=48458&)* is a free ORE game you can download. If it does turn out to be the system you heard of and you want to buy a fantasy game using it, the [*Reign Enchiridion* is a dense book for a mere $10](http://www.arcdream.com/zencart/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=7&products_id=18), and that gets you print *and* PDF.